# netsuite customer center saved search

Tags: netsuite

I have created a saved search for a custom record with available filters. I have then added a Customer Center category called Information and in this category added a Link to the search form. I have added the necessary permissions to the customer center role to view the record and the search form. However, the search form does not appear in the customer center. 
For it to appear I need to set permission on the custom record to No Permissions. The result is that when the search is run in the customer center, the user can view and edit the search result lines and hence the custom record...
Is there any way to avoid this: allow user to view search results but not view and edit the records? I have seen I can publish a saved search, however I would rather have a search form that allows the user to use the available filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response and solutions.
In my particular case, I'm adding a link to a custom record search.
I found that by restricting the permissions to the custom record to Edit only, than the user is not able to drill down to view or edit the custom record.
I did this as follows:
Setup > Users/Roles > Edit my customer center role > Permissions (sub tab) > Custom Record (sublist) > my custom record > Restrict > set to Edit Only.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to avoid access to the custom record you can use a WorkFlow or a UserEvent script to blowup the request, with a nice message of course ;)

If I had this requirement I would probably do something like this:

1. Redirect to a page (SuiteLet) with clietn script deployed to pop-up a message "Access denied, fool!"
2. Once the user confirmed (i.e. clicked 'OK') I would redirect back to the search results

You'd lose any filters and scrolling settings but that's not a big price to pay.  Even then you can get into parsing the nlobjRequest and look for the filters as params that you can pass down the redirect chain and then use nlapiRequestURL with the params to restore your filters.  I don't know if that last part is actually possible but it's a concept.